# EF Migration on Test Database breaking all integration tests after merge

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-4.5, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working on a .NET 4.5.2 project that creates an In-Memory db from an `.mdf` file every time we run the Integration tests.

The db works fairly well most of the time, but sometimes, when we make changes on the schema of a table, or add/delete a table altogether, we get problems like the following:

```
Message: 
    OneTimeSetUp: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : There is already an object named 'SomeTable' in the database
```

We have narrowed it down to the fact that EF migrations get all messed up when we want to update the test db schema after a merge ([known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/teams)). It seems like adding an empty migration everytime we have one of these issues fixes the problem, however, that workaround it's very tacky.

My question is: **Is there a way to prevent this kind of issues? Maybe a cleaner workaround?**

For some extra content, I'll describe how we're doing things (maybe we're messing up somehow):

We have a `Db.mdf` file that gets loaded by a `LocalDbHelper` before running any test:

[image]

With this code:

```
public static void PrepareEmptyDb()
    {
        var migrationConfiguration = new Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true,
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true
        };

        var migrator = new DbMigrator(migrationConfiguration);
        migrator.Update();
    }
```

This code is meant to be run in a `OneTimeSetup` at the `IntegrationTestBase` class.

And this is the code in the `Configuration` class (this is at our code first `Persistance` project, where all migrations reside):

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context.DbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(Context.DbContext context)
    {
        context.Settings.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.Name,
            new Setting { Name = SettingNames.RoundingDirection, Value = "Up" },
            new Setting { Name = SettingNames.RoundingValue, Value = "10" },
            new Setting { Name = SettingNames.RateCacheLifetimeMinutes, Value = "30" });
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since this issue has really been annoying us for a while now.

**EDIT:** I've found [this link](https://kaliko.com/blog/ef-migrations-problem-after-merge/) that seem to suggest that, for older versions of .NET, this workaround was the recommended fix suggested by Microsoft themselves, but if anyone has a better way to fix it (or to automatize it) it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you change the database the schema changes and you also have to update the mapping which is the linking between the c# classes and the table/fields of the database.  The migration is doing the updating of the mapping.  You can just update the mapping instead of doing a migration.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.core.mapping?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've been reviewing the link you sent, but I don't see how I would be able to update the .mdf file from code using the classes within the namespace you provided. Care to elaborate a little bit more, perhaps? Sorry, I'm not very familiar with that namespace.

Comment: There are two approaches for updating database 1) Code first 2) Database first.  I believe in Core you can only use the first method Code First.  I've been told that Database first does not work in Core. Does in Net.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/

Comment: Database first works just fine in EF Core, please don't spread misinformation.

Comment: Yeah, I've worked with both approaches (both on Framework and Core, although in core it's slightly more complicated since you don't get the "Update model from db" button and need to run some commands and be very tidy with your db -using SSDT is a must). That being said, I'm working on FW 4.5.2 and I don't think it's feasible for us (for budgetary reasons) to move on to DB first at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an empty migration seems to be the only way to fix this. No workarounds or fixes other than upgrading to Core, sadly.